# How do I correct Android Studio's SDK manager's cache folder's location?

Tags: android-studio

In my Android Studio (Version 3.5), I have the SDK folder setup correctly, but when I try to update Android Studio, it fails because it attempts to download the SDK packages to a non-existing location.

My SDK is setup to use:

> D:\ProgramFiles\Android\sdk

Android studio attempts download to:

> F:\ProgramFiles\Android\sdk.temp\PackageOperation0x\

where x is a natural number between 2 and 6 in my case.

The drive F is not existing in my machine.

In which file do I rectify this path?

Cheers.

The following are screenshots of what I see.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsPhT.png) Correct SDK path.
[Correct SDK path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsPhT.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTMki.png) Wrong Cache path.
[Wrong Cache path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTMki.png)

Answer (score 0):

find the the file .installData in .install folder and change the correct path

example

"D:\ProgramFiles\Android\sdk\platforms\android-16\.installer"

#Tue Apr 06 15:06:39 VET 2021
class=com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller
path=E:\ProgramFiles\Android\sdk\.temp\PackageOperation03

change for

#Tue Apr 06 15:06:39 VET 2021
class=com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller
path=D:\ProgramFiles\Android\sdk\.temp\PackageOperation03